# Identifying Reflection.Emit-generated assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, reflection.emit, dynamically-generated

Is there a simple way to identify Reflection.Emit-generated assemblies? When processing all assemblies loaded into an application domain, `Assembly` instances of dynamically generated assemblies don't behave the same as for standard assemblies. For example, accessing the `CodeBase` property leads to an exception:

```
string codeBase;
try
{
    codeBase = assembly.CodeBase;
}
catch(NotSupportedException)
{
    // assemblies generated via Reflection.Emit throw an exception when CodeBase is accessed
    codeBase = null;
}
```

Is there a better way to recognize this situation and avoid the `try … catch` block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
if (assembly is System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder) {
    // It's dynamic
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't [Assembly.IsDynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332812.aspx) answer your question? It may be that it is new in .Net 4.0.